# Availability of methods defined in Module.singleton_class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Hi I'm a bit confused over Ruby's object model here:

```
class Module
  # `hello` should be readily available within all regular classes
  def hello
    'Hello World'
  end
end

# `special` should be available within all regular singleton classes
class Module
  class << self
    def special
      puts 'This is the special method defined in Module.singleton_class'
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  hello  # => 'Hello World'
  # special  # this correctly raises an error here
  # special should only available in MyClass.singleton_class and it actually is.
  # However `hello` method shouldn't be available in `MyClass.singleton_class` (only in MyClass) but yet it is. Why?
  class << self
    special # This only works here as it should
    hello  # but strangely this works too! It shouldn't though...
  end
end
```

Could you please explain to me why is method `hello` available in `MyClass.singleton_class` since it is defined in `Module` and not `Module.singleton_class`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why:

```
  class MyClass
    class << self
      hello  # but strangely this works too! It shouldn't though...
      self.class.ancestors # => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
    end
  end
```

`self` there is a `Class`, which is a `Module` to which you patched-in the method `hello`, so it is available like any other inherited method.

Same for that other usage of `hello`.

Comment: Right. I see. I followed the inheritance chain using an alternative "route" by doing `self.ancestors # => [#<Class:MyClass>, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` and came to the conclusion that `hello` is Module instance method destined to be used only by regular classes. I missed the fact that a singleton class is still a class though...